# Having trouble referencing .NET Standard class library using SQLProvider from .NET Core project

Tags: .net-core, f#, .net-standard, type-providers

Reproduction of problem here: https://github.com/Arrow7000/SqlProviderTest

---

I'm fairly new to the .NET world so am having trouble wrapping my head around exactly what the problem is.

I've tried to use the SQL type provider directly in an F# .NET Core project, but had a bunch of problems getting it to work. From what I can tell that's due to incompatibilities between .net core and type providers.

So what I am trying instead is to have the SQL type provider code encapsulated in a .NET Standard project that I can reference from my main Core project.

I've managed to reproduce the problem in a minimal [GitHub repo located here](https://github.com/Arrow7000/SqlProviderTest) which demonstrates both that

1. the type provider is working in Visual Studio 2019 with IntelliSense, but
2. despite this I still get a build error when I try to start the Main project

The build error is

```
Unable to find the file 'C:\projects\SqlProviderTest\SQLStuff\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\SQLStuff.dll' in any of
 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.2.0\ref\netcoreapp2.2
 C:\projects\SqlProviderTest\Main
 C:\Users\Aron\.nuget\packages\fsharp.core\4.6.2\lib\netstandard1.6
```

Why isn't the project reference simply working as expected? I've tried adding `<Private>True</Private>` to the project reference but that didn't make any difference

---

P.S. in case it matters, I'm developing on Windows but the app gets deployed on a Docker container.

Comment: This is a very specialized question that would be better placed in the SQLProvider github. My experience is that SQLProvider is very fiddly to get to work with .Net Core. If you are not free to use MSSQL instead of MySQL you will get a more robust type provider in SqlClient.